# Set Maximum Length of Multiple TextFields

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I found this code from another stack overflow post

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger upperRightLength = [upperRight.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperRightLength > 1) ? NO : YES;
        }
```

I need to run this same code (which works great) on more than one textField..

I tried this but it did not seem to run correctly, and did not have the same effect!

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger upperRightLength = [upperRight.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperRightLength > 1) ? NO : YES;

    NSUInteger upperLeftLength = [upperLeft.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperLeftLength > 1) ? NO : YES;
}
```

I don't know what else to do! Thank you so much for your help!!

EDIT:
I have now tried another code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger upperRightLength = [upperRight.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger upperLeftLength = [upperLeft.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperLeftLength > 1 &&  upperRightLength > 1 ) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Now the same thing seems to happen. Which ever text field I click on first (lets say upperLeft) I am still able to type as many characters as I want. But then when I click on the other textfield (upperRight) I am only able to type 1 character. I have tried starting with the (upperRight) first and I see the same results... where the (upperRight) will allow me to type as many as I want, and the (upperLeft) will only allow me to type 1 character! This is so weird!! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of the delegate method. This method gives you the textField that is being edited so you can use the reference to `textField` given to you and not use an ivar

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
  NSUInteger length = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
  return !(length > 1);
}
```

---

### update

There are many different ways to handle different lengths for different fields. The simplest would be something like:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
  NSInteger maxLength = 1;

  if (textField == self.myOtherTextField) {
    maxLength = 2;
  }

  NSUInteger length = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
  return !(length > maxLength);
}
```

Comment: Yes! That is what I tires originally, which worked perfectly fine, the problem is I need to run that same code for multiple textfields.   I just don't know what to do to make that possible with the code given above! Thanks!!

Comment: Have you set the delegate for each textField?

Comment: haha I am not completely sure. This is what i have done though.. in the .h <UITextFieldDelegate>. and in the .m     self.upperRight.delegate = self;

Comment: you need to do it for upperLeft textfield, too.

Comment: Is this method being called when you update either of the textfields? Can you show your exact code you are trying to use and setup of textfields.

Comment: Sure! I really haven't done any thing else besides setting up the delegates, and using this exact code all by it self..

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger upperRightLength = [upperRight.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger upperLeftLength = [upperLeft.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperLeftLength > 1 &&  upperRightLength > 1 ) ? NO : YES;
}

Comment: That's not the code I gave. That will tie the two textfields together which is not what you want. What's the result of running `NSLog(@"%@ %@", upperRight.delegate, upperLeft.delegate);`

Comment: Okay I got it!! haha I used your code and it worked!!

Comment: I do have one more question though... I have one textfield that needs to have 3 characters.. but this code allows only one (which I need for the other 2 fields) What should I do for allowing just one specific textField to have 3 characters? Thank you so much! I really do appreciate it!!

Comment: Updated answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You'll never calculate `upperLeftLength` because you return just before. So, what you need to do is calculate `upperLeftLength` and `upperRightLength`, then determine if it returns **YES** or **NO**. Put a breakpoint on the line `upperLeftLength`, you see that your breakpoint will never be hit.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger upperRightLength = [upperRight.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    NSUInteger upperLeftLength = [upperLeft.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (upperLeftLength > 1 &&  upperRightLength > 1 ) ? NO : YES;
}
```

would work.

Comment: Thank you! So now the same thing seems to happen. Which ever text field I click on first (lets say upperLeft) I am still able to type as many characters as I want. But then when I click on the other textfield (upperRight) I am only able to type 1 character. I have tried starting with the (upperRight) first and I see the same results... where the (upperRight) will allow me to type as many as I want, and the (upperLeft) will only allow me to type 1 character! This is so weird!! Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the `didChange` method like the `UITextViewDelegate` method, but as we know the `UITextFieldDelegate` does not have a `didChange` method. You can manually add behaviour. You can use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, but personally I would advise not to override methods unless you absolutely have to.

You can add behaviour using:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And in the target method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField{

    //handle code
}
```

The advantage here is, you do not have to wait for the user to type another character before knowing your code should take effect. As soon as they reach the limit, your code will take effect.

If your `textField`s are global, you may access them here directly with `textField == upperRight`, or if they are defined in blocks, just set their `tag`s and check with `textField.tag == <tagValueOfTextField>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

     if (_card_Number==textField){
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
            {
                return NO;
            }

            NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] 
               - range.length;
            return newLength <= 19;

     }else if (_card_cvnf==textField){
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
            {
                return NO;
            }

            NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
            return newLength <= 4;
        }else{
                        return NO;
        }

    }
}
```